# Template type deduction C++

Tags: c++

I am getting an error `qualified-id in declaration before ‘<’ token` from the following code:

```
// g++ -std=c++20 example.cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename U = int>
struct Example {
    template <typename T>
    static void execute() {
        std::cout << "Hey" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Example::execute<float>();
}
```

When I include the type for Example, such as `Example<int>::execute<float>()` it compiles successfully. Shouldn't the compiler be able to deduce the type since I specified it as default value?

Comment: `Example<>::execute<float>()`

Comment: You didn't provide a default for T

Comment: @doug `T` is given a template argument explicitly.

Comment: There is nothing to deduce here. The issue is the subject of [P2601R0](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2601r0.html) which my or may not become a part of the next standard.

Comment: @user17732522. Yep. missed that somehow. duh. + your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class template argument deduction only applies when creating objects.

That is `Example e;` will deduce `Example<int> e;` via the default argument.

You are not creating an object though, and `Example` is not a class.  You must include a template argument list.  In this case, it can be empty though, since the template argument includes a default:

```
Example<>::execute<float>();
```